# Use induction to prove coloring question

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, induction, contest-math, coloring

Suppose we have  ${n}$ circles inside a ${2D}$ plane  , we know that some of these circles might be colliding therefore creating a shared space between them .

prove we can color all of the plane with only 2 colors in a way that zones with shared bounds (lines)  have different colors   .

I am really stuck here between using weak induction or the strong induction . I don't know what to consider in strong induction , I tried proving that forms the circle can form while colliding is finite and limited and then have my base for strong induction but it did not work.

Another problem I have is with the sizes of the circles , does that affect the way we approach the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a colouring for $1$ circle: the inside is red, the outside is white. Now given a colouring for $k$ circles, any new circle has an inside and an outside, so we flip the colour of all regions inside the circle. Convince yourself that this is a colouring for $k+1$ circles and conclude.